# Must be a simple mistake I'm making: Flex CSS style not working in a trival case

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, flex-builder-3

I must be making a simple mistake (new to Flex). Here is main.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
                backgroundColor="#ff0000">
    <mx:Style source="/testing123.css"/>
    <mx:Canvas top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" styleName="bg-lowlight" >
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

and here is testing123.css:

```
.bg-lowlight

    {
        backgroundColor: #003366;
    }
```

The Canvas renders fine in design mode (a nice deep blue) but when I run the application (either in the browser or in the Flash Player) the frame is red (the color from the Application tag). If I specify the color for the Canvas directly, instead of through the styleName, it works as expected (blue canvas at runtime).

I'm using FlexBuilder3, and would much rather put colors in a .css file than on every Flex element!

Help!!!

*** Additional problem description ... has nothing to do with an external .css file.  Even if I declare the CSS styles within the main.xml file, it still looks fine in Design mode and wrong when it runs. I am completely stymied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" backgroundColor="#ff0000">
    <mx:Style > 
.bg-lowlight
{
    backgroundColor: #003366;
}
    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Canvas top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" styleName="bg-lowlight" id="canvas1">
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...with CookieOfFortune's help I tracked down the root of the problem:

- the CSS class name (*bg-lowlight*) was invalid. The '-' is not allowed

that's what happens, I guess, when you guess at what is logical!

Comment: do you really think that '-' is not allowed in css class name?

Answer (score 1):

The active directory changes when you run the application, so "/testing123.css/" no longer refers to the correct file.

EDIT: It's actually REALLY annoying.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the correct source= value to for the mx:Style tag, so I looked in the bin-debug folder...and the .css file isn't there!  I assumed it would have been copied to the bin folder. How can I get that to happen (or include in the .swf)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice...but I modified the original example to switch to internal <mx:Style> instead of external .CSS definitions, and the file still looks great in design time but wrong when it runs.

Comment: is it running a cached version?

Comment: I have IE set to "Check for newer version of stored pages - Every time I visit the webpage".  That should force re-fetch of the page, right?

Comment: Not certain, since the html would still be the same.

Comment: Yet another problem with my original...the class name had a '-' in it (bg-lowlight). No warnings, looks fine in Design mode...but doesn't work.  I think that may have been the root of the problem. Removing the '-' from the class name seems to do the trick.